# $firebaseObject not found when injecting Firebase into AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm running a simple Firebase App with only 3 files. When I run in the browser I get this error when trying to connect to my firebase DB:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24firebaseObjectProvider%20%3C-%20%24firebaseObject

Here is my app.js:

```
(function() {

  var app = angular.module("scheduleApp", ['firebase']);

  app.controller('MainController',['$scope','$firebaseObject',function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://gajobs.firebaseio.com/");
    $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
  }]);

})();
```

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="scheduleApp" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GA Jobs</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.0/journal/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">

  <div class="page-header text-center">       
    <h1>GA Job Board</h1>        
  </div>
  <div class="row times">

    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">

      <h2>Contact</h2>

      <div class="time-slot">       
        <input type="checkbox" id="contact">
        <label for="contact">Tableu</label>
      </div>
    </div>    

  </div>

  <p class="text-center">    
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="reset()">Reset</a>
  </p>

</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure what is wrong here, it seems to not like the $firebaseObject that I am trying t use...

Comment: What if you try with a newer version of `Firebase` and `AngularFire`, like the ones shown [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-scripts)?

Comment: Just tried with the newer versions from the link I sent before and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you're using an old version of AngularFire.

`$firebaseObject` and `$firebaseArray` were introduced in 1.0.

In 0.8 you have to use `$firebase(ref).$asObject()`, but please don't use this old version as it is not supported.

Comment: Ahh! yes it worked, I've run into alot of errors with the firebase docs...its very cool, but I'm struggling to get my head around it

Comment: What errors have you run into with the docs? They should be up to date.

Comment: Sorry worded that wrong. I've run into alot of trouble trying to set up a basic firebase app while reading through the docs. All errors are on my end.